# Extracting substrings enclosed by number-independant double quotations with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a large set of data where I need to extract the last string enclosed by double quotation using JavaScript. Each text can look like this:

> some text some text some text "some quote" some text

Or this

> Some text "some quote" some text "and some quote"

Or why not like this

> Some text " some text "some quote" some text

And so on.

As you can see the problem is in the lack of predictability of the dataset and I can't wrap my head around this problem.
My progress has only managed to extract the first assurance:

```
$( $("[id^=node-]") ).each(function() {

  var string = $(this).next().text();
  array = string.match(/"([^"]+)"/);

});
```

Comment: Like [`/"([^"]+)"(?=[^"]*$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/jC0iR8/1)? You forgot to indicate what final result you need to get for your example inputs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/jC0iR8/2

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC0iR8/3) (with multiline and global options on). In JS, that is not necessary since you will be matching individual strings.

Comment: Great @WiktorStribiżew !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's really fine :)

Comment: Do you want to ignore previous match if last one doesn't have closing quotes?

Comment: The most simple solution for getting the last quoted match is to put a greedy dot in front of the capture. [`var res = /.*"([^"]+)"/.exec(str); alert(res[1]);`](https://jsfiddle.net/271269mL/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead `(?=[^"]*$)` after your pattern to make sure you only match the last pair of quotes:

```js
var s = ["some text some text some text \"some quote\" some text", "Some text \"some quote\" some text \"and some quote\"", "Some text \" some text \"some quote\" some text"];
var res = s.map(r => (m = r.match(/"([^"]*)"(?=[^"]*$)/)) ? m[1] : "");
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

And here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC0iR8/3).

The pattern breakdown:

- `"` - match a double quote
- `([^"]*)` - match and capture the contents between the double quotes as `[^"]*` matches any 0+ characters other than a double quote
- `"` - a double quote
- `(?=[^"]*$)` - fail the match if there is a double quote somewhere to the right of the last matched `"` up to the end of the string (in other words, require no `"` up to the end of the string).

For those who think a lookahead is an overkill another working regex should be

```
/"([^"]*)"[^"]*$/
```

```js
var s = ["some text some text some text \"some quote\" some text", "Some text \"some quote\" some text \"and some quote\"", "Some text \" some text \"some quote\" some text"];
var res = s.map(r => (m = r.match(/"([^"]*)"[^"]*$/)) ? m[1] : "");
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Explanation is the same but the lookahead is turned into a consuming subpattern `[^"]*$` that actually matches (and consumes characters) all 0+ symbols other than `"` up to the end of string.

Comment: I love negative look-aheads as much as the next guy, except when they are not needed.

Comment: @torazaburo: What do you mean by "not needed"? It is necessary here if one wants to get a substring between the **last two double quotes**. See the demo, remove the lookahead, and you will feel the difference. At least, it is a working and correct solution, no need downvoting. Unless you feel like doing that which is a very bad idea.

Comment: If the match value required must be from the quote to the quote the lookahead is a must anyway. One cannot say no lookahead is not necessary just because requirements for what should be in  Group 0 and 1 are not precisely defined in the OP.

Comment: Just noticed you called this a negative lookahead, but actually it's just a lookahead, right?

Answer (score 1):

Add `g` attribute:

```
array = string.match(/"([^"]+)"/g);
```

To search globally.

### See it working:

https://regex101.com/r/dM8gQ6/1

Comment: You misread the question, which asks **the last string enclosed**.

Answer (score 1):

If regex is not a mandate, then try

```
    var someText = 'some text some text some text "some quote" some text';
    var matchedItems = someText.split("\"").filter(function(value,index){if (index%2==1) return true});
```

```js
var someText = 'Some text "some quote" some text "and some quote"';
    var matchedItems = someText.split("\"").filter(function(value,index){if (index%2==1) return true});
    document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(matchedItems, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Interesting, but this doesn't return *the last string enclosed by double quotation*, but rather all of them, and it will fail if the quotes are not balanced.

Comment: @torazaburo last enclosed one can be fetched by getting the last item from array - `matchedItems.pop()`.. Let me check for the unbalanced input part. Did OP asked for it and what should it return?

Comment: I think it's the penultimate item. With regard to the unbalanced case, if there are an odd number of quotes, according to his second example, he seems to want to ignore the first one.

Comment: @torazaburo OP wants to ignore previous match if next one doesn't have closing quotes? Not sure he has conveyed the same. Let me check with him

Answer (score 0):

For some people, lookaheads are the hammer they try to pound in every nail with.

Look for the last quoted string:

```
/"([^"]*)"[^"]*$/
 ^^^^^^^^^              STRING WITH QUOTES
   ^^^^^                STRING WITHOUT QUOTES (CAPTURING THIS)
          ^^^^^         OTHER STUFF WITHOUT QUOTES
               ^        END OF STRING
```

Comment: You could just leave me a note that the lookaround is not necessary, and I could adjust it to your taste. The matching pattern used in this answer is just the same as mine.